# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project timesheet

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

i downloaded a maven project from github and i am trying to mvn install but I am getting this error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project timesheet: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeTags -> [Help 1]
```

this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>tn.esprit.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>timesheet</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>timesheet</name>
    <description>timesheet</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
      ... 
    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

the following are my Apache Maven and Java version :

Apache Maven 3.6.3
Java version: 11.0.9

Comment: First: Why do you change outputDirectory `<outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>` seond why overwriting `<maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>`? Do you have that project on github or alike?

Comment: yes it's from github

Comment: can you give the url otherwise it's not possible to help here...